# Target Bootstrap HTML element with data-bs-target from another element in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a Bootstrap (5) Offcanvas menu from an icon click event in Angular 12. I have tried many methods including wrapping it in a button (this works with one icon but I have an `<fa-stack></fa-stack>` element and this doesn't work for that for some reason), targeting the element `id` of a hidden button such as below:

```
<button #menuOpen [hidden]="true" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#slide-out-menu" 
type="button" aria-controls="slide-out-menu">
</button>

<fa-stack (click)="menuOpen.click()">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCircle" stackItemSize="2x"></fa-icon>
  <fa-icon [icon]="icon" [inverse]="true" stackItemSize="1x"></fa-icon>
</fa-stack>

<div #slideOutMenu class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" id="slide-out-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-label">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

and also adding an `[ngClass]="{'show', showMenu}"` directive as well which doesn't work.

Is there a way to target this element and show it from a click event (not directly on the button)?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

If the hidden button and the `<fa-stack>` element are in the same component, you can use `ViewChild` to target the hidden button. And then use its `nativeElement` to alter the DOM with Renderer2:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `
    <button #menuOpen [hidden]="true" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#slide-out-menu" 
type="button" aria-controls="slide-out-menu">
    </button>

    <fa-stack (click)="toggleMenuButton()">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faCircle" stackItemSize="2x"></fa-icon>
        <fa-icon [icon]="icon" [inverse]="true" stackItemSize="1x"></fa-icon>
    </fa-stack>
  `
})
export class App {

    @ViewChild('menuOpen') menuButton: ElementRef;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    toggleMenuButton() {
        // Add "show" CSS-class to button
        this.renderer.addClass(this.menuButton.nativeElement, 'show');

        // Remove "show" CSS-class from button
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.menuButton.nativeElement, 'show');

        // Add "hide" CSS-class to button
        this.renderer.addClass(this.menuButton.nativeElement, 'hide');

        // Remove "hide" CSS-class from button
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.menuButton.nativeElement, 'hide');
    }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION 2**

If they're not in the same component, you can alternatively achieve this by using the `querySelector()` with pure javascript and search for an element with a certain attribute and value. So in your case, use this code to get a `button` that has attribute `data-bs-target` with value `#slide-out-menu`:

```js
var targetElement = document.querySelector("button[data-bs-target='#slide-out-menu']");
console.log(targetElement);
```

```html
<button #menuOpen [hidden]="true" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#slide-out-menu" type="button" aria-controls="slide-out-menu">
    I am the button
</button>
```

And then alter the CSS or classes of the `targetElement`

```js
const showMenu = () => {
    targetElement.classList.add("show");
    targetElement.classList.remove("hide");
}

const hideMenu = () => {
    targetElement.classList.remove("show");
    targetElement.classList.add("hide");
}
```